# Can I install a service worker without permission of push notification?

Tags: push-notification, permissions, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

When I write the code like this, I get permission for notification when registering with a service worker.
I want to allow notification after launching the application added to the home screen, so I want to prevent the notification permission from being displayed when registering with a service worker, is it possible?

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window){
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(pathServiceWorker)
        .then(function(swReg){
            swReg.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true})
                .then(function(sub) {
                    console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.error('subscribeError',error);
                });
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.error('ServiceWorkerError',error);
        });
} else {
    console.warn('Pushmessagingisnotsupported');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check this [Handle Permission Denied](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/#handle_permission_denied) documentation. You may refer to the sample code on how to disable the push button when the user is not yet subscribed.

```
function updateBtn() {
  if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Push Messaging Blocked.';
    pushButton.disabled = true;
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);
    return;
  }

  if (isSubscribed) {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messaging';
  } else {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Enable Push Messaging';
  }

  pushButton.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I will try to be able to register after confirming permission of notification!

Comment: I saw a sample of "Handle Permission Denied" and got a solution hint.
There are places where "subscribe ()" is done in places other than the presented code,
Permission for notice was requested.
Thank you for helping!

Comment: @aiosl - do you have a solution for this? I don't want to show any prompt to the user for permission, but wanted to send the notifications.